# android:How to add a button to the top of the list view

Tags: android

In My application I want to add a button to the top of the List view. It means at the top button is there after that list view is continued.

Following is my code. using this I am getting

> 05-23 11:44:34.407:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1348):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.Elgifto/com.Elgifto.Egender}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException.

**Egender.java**

```
package com.Elgifto;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Egender extends ListActivity{

    Button b1;
    ListView lv;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        b1=new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Done");
        lv.addHeaderView(b1);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, GENDER));



        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        setContentView(lv);
    }


    private static final String[] GENDER = new String[] {
       "Male","Female"
    };
}
```

**gender.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">


   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 0):

your should write setContentView(R.layout.gender) first below super and ListView in xml should have the id like this    android:id="@+id/android:list" not

android:id="@+id/list" because you class extends ListView .

Answer (score 0):

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You cannot search for any views until they are inflated. Call setContentView() within your layout first, and modify it after.

Answer (score 0):

you must setContentView before use any view..
so, try this..

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.gender);
 lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        b1=new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Done");
.
.
.
etc
```

and you alos missed to define GENDER variable..

so first define it like as

```
String GENDER = new String{"Male","Female"};
```